# How can i inejct only one intance of my DbContext per request in my controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

My controller needs two types of service and both need to have the same interface of dbcontext,

```
public class MyController : Controller
    {
        protected readonly ISomeService _some;
               protected reaonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork

        public MyController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ISomeService some) 
        {
            _some = some;
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork

        }
```

//This is my configuration

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(x =>  
   {

    x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("coon"));

  });
```

Comment: How have you added your services to the DI container? By default, DbContext is added as a scoped service.

Comment: please post your current  DI configuration

Comment: Why would you need the instance to be the same?

Comment: In what scope are the two services registered with the container?

Comment: (how) Did you verify that the DbContext instances in your 2 services are not the same instance?

Answer (score 3):

[From the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#entity-framework-contexts) :

> **Entity Framework contexts**
>
> Entity Framework contexts should be added to the service container
>   using the scoped lifetime. This is handled automatically with a call
>   to the AddDbContext method when registering the database context.
>   Services that use the database context should also use the scoped
>   lifetime.

So AddDbContext would add it as a scoped life time.

You need to make sure that the controllers / or other  places where this is used, are also added in DI as the Scoped items.

Scoped lifetime services are created once per request.

Comment: services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
services.AddScoped(typeof(ISomeService), typeof(SomeService));
Some Service Need Repository And Unitofwork
Reposytory needs DbContext

Answer (score 0):

I found the Issuse my problem was that i used AsyncSaveChanges insted of SaveChanges but my services get the same instace thank you all :) !

Comment: You should be using `SaveChangesAsync`. `SaveChanges` just blocks on `SaveChangesAsync`, and blocking is bad. Most likely you're failing to await the async call properly.

Comment: Yes but in my  MVC project that I'm doing, I don't really need to have  async methods is okay for me  having  that block, so I don't see this like a bad thing but thanks 